# Load a resource from a .jar not as a stream

Tags: java, jar

I am making a small tool in Eclipse which needs to run a C executable - the file is in one of the packages and runs fine inside the IDE.

When I try to package it as a .jar though, nothing seems to work - `InvocationTargetException`, `NullPointerException`, they've all showed up while trying to fix it, and I'm pretty sure the .jar doesn't work because files can't be accessed inside it without using `getResourceAsStream()`. I've tried using `getResource()` but it just returns variations of where the file should be - but it can't be accessed as it's in a jar.

Many questions here of the same nature are answered by using `getResourceAsStream()`, but I'm not sure that works for an executable. Is there a way to access a file inside a .jar other than the resource stream method? Or am I just thinking of this the wrong way, and there's a simple solution I'm missing?

Comment: Why not take the file *out* of the jar executable and make sure that it is in the classpath?

Comment: No, there is no other way. A resource inside a JAR must be accessed with an `InputStream`. What do you want to do then? Executable should be outside of a JAR. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar

Comment: JARs are for **Java** resources. An executable can hardly been seen as a resource ...